# What token to be used to generate UserAssertion in AAD in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

We want to use AcquireTokenAsync to acquire the tokens on behalf of user using the following syntax

```
public static async Task<UserTokenCache> GetAccessTokens(string userUniqueId)
    {
        UserTokenCache cache = null;
        AuthenticationContext authContext = null;
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
        AuthenticationResult powerBIResult = null;
        AuthenticationResult graphResult = null;
        bool isAdalException = false;
        try
        {
            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userUniqueId));

            powerBIResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(pbiResourceID, credential, new UserIdentifier(userUniqueId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

            graphResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceId, credential, new UserIdentifier(userUniqueId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

            cache = new UserTokenCache
            {
                GraphAccessToken = graphResult.AccessToken,
                PBIAccessToken = powerBIResult.AccessToken,
                PBITokenExpires = powerBIResult.ExpiresOn,
                GraphTokenExpires = graphResult.ExpiresOn
            };

        }
        catch (JsonException je)
        {
            ExceptionLogger.LogInApplicationInsight(je);
            HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                       new AuthenticationProperties(),
                       OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
        catch (AdalException ae)
        {
            ExceptionLogger.LogInApplicationInsight(ae);
            if (ae.ErrorCode == "failed_to_acquire_token_silently")
            {
                isAdalException = true;       
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                           new AuthenticationProperties(),
                           OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionLogger.LogInApplicationInsight(ex);
        }
        if(isAdalException)
        {
            try
            {

                string cacheValue = Convert.ToString(cacheManager.get(userUniqueId));
                string decryptedCache = CryptographyUtility.Decrypt(cacheValue);
                cache = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserTokenCache>(decryptedCache);

                UserAssertion pbiAssertion = new UserAssertion(cache.PBIAccessToken, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", UserProperties.UserName);
                UserAssertion graphAssertion = new UserAssertion(cache.GraphAccessToken, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", UserProperties.UserName);

                cache = null;

                powerBIResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(pbiResourceID, credential, pbiAssertion);
                graphResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, credential, graphAssertion);

                cache = new UserTokenCache
                {
                    GraphAccessToken = graphResult.AccessToken,
                    PBIAccessToken = powerBIResult.AccessToken,
                    PBITokenExpires = powerBIResult.ExpiresOn,
                    GraphTokenExpires = graphResult.ExpiresOn
                };
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionLogger.LogInApplicationInsight(ex);
            }
        }
        return cache;

    }
```

If we use cache.PBIAccessToken and cache.GraphAccessToken to calculate user assertions which are used in AcquireTokenAsync method, it is throwing the error that TenantId is mismatch. In this case, what is the token which needs to be used to calculate UserAssertion.

Comment: According to this github example it appears you need the User's access token. See lines 133 to 137 and compare to yours.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/master/TodoListService/Controllers/TodoListController.cs

Comment: @Shelby115, Thank you for the answer. But BootstrapContext is coming out to be null in my case.

Comment: I have added system.identityModel chunk shown [here](http://bartwullems.blogspot.in/2013/08/the-configuration-section-cannot-be.html). Still no luck

Comment: Could you please tell more about your scenario?

Comment: We embedded Power BI reports on Azure App and Power BI tokens need to refresh every hour.We use above function to get the refresh tokens. In most cases, AcquireTokenSilentAsync works without an issue. But it fails few times with AdalException of type "failed_to_acquire_token_silently" which requires us to call AcquireTokenAsync with USerAssertion. I am unable to get the token which should be used for getting UserAssertion. As suggested by @Shelby115, I try to use BootstrapContent.Token but BootStrapContext is always null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally , we usually use AcquireTokenAsync to get the access token and refresh token the first time user login . After that you could get the token silently(invoke AcquireTokenSilentAsync to get the accessToken ), it will get the token from the TokenCache or silently use refreshToken . If access tokens and refresh tokens both expired ,you may get AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException( Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken) .

Then you could catch that exception ,  and invoking`HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);` to redirect user to azure ad login page , after login , user call api with AcquireTokenSilentAsync  will work since access token/refresh token exist in cache ,and not expired. Your code in `if(isAdalException)` is useless if i understand your requirement correctly .